# % Stacked bar chart

Tags: r

I am creating stacked bar chart using `prop.table`, below is syntax.

```
barplot(prop.table(table(df$V1,df$V2),2)*100)
```

I have a csv file with data in the following format

```
V1, V2
Value1, Group1
Value2, Group2
Value3, Group1
Value4, Group2
Value1, Group1
Value2, Group2
Value3, Group1
Value4, Group2
Value1, Group1
Value2, Group2
Value3, Group1
Value4, Group2
Value1, Group1
Value2, Group2
Value3, Group1
Value4, Group2
Value1, Group1
Value2, Group2
Value3, Group1
Value4, Group2
```

Now I want to add data value, legend and colour to each categories in V2 in plot, Is there anyway I can display these information in chart?

Comment: I able to add legend and colour using below revised code, but legend covers plot area barplot(prop.table(table(df$V1,df$V2),2)*100,col=c("darkblue", "red","Green","Orange"))
legend("topright", 
       legend = levels(unique(df$V2), 
       fill = c("darkblue", "red","Green","Orange"), bty = "n")

Comment: Readers can help you better if you provide your data frame.  Use dput and insert that in the question.  Also, you mean "stacked" bar chart.  And, why do you use the ggplot2 label?

Comment: @lawyeR, Thanks for your reply, I tried to insert format of CSV file which I am using. I was not sure how to insert data frame in question. Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Insert the data frame with `dput(your_data_frame)`, or if your data frame is very big `dput(droplevels(head(your_data_frame)))`. It's copy/pasteable into R and preserves column classes.

Comment: Here's a first effort at creating data that looks like yours and plotting it in a barplot (using `ggplot2`). Let me know if this is close to what you want and I can help you get the rest of the way there.
http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=mVHKwHFy